# MVC3 Access to Path Is Denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I am getting the following error when trying to deploy an MVC3 site.

I have searched and understand what to do with the error with acccess to the file system, but I will be deploying to a shared environment and so cannot RDP in (i.e. I have no control).

Is there anything I can do via the web.config or another means?

Sorry if the answer is obvious.

**Error**

> > Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SharedSiteTest\tmp\Views\Index.cshtml' is denied.
> >     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
> >
> > Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SharedSiteTest\tmp\Views\Index.cshtml' is denied.
> >
> > ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
> >
> > To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Comment: You will have to talk to your hosting provider. We cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks People. I was really hoping to avoid it, but will do.

Comment: What did you find out?

Comment: Sorry. Bad form to leave something in limbo. I was trying to deploy this structure (http://www.scribd.com/doc/140181293/Setting-Up-an-MVC4-Multi-Tenant-Site-v1-1 ) to a shared hosting environment. In the end, the host would not add rights to the tmp folder to allow the site access the dynamically built views. I moved it over to to a VM, gave the application pool rights to the tmp folder and it worked no problem.